# how to add a paragraph to an already good answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette

I would like to add a paragraph to this answer: https://law.stackexchange.com/a/84102/46677

I want to explain that privileges are another category of information that are excluded as evidence and explain the reasons why.

I added a comment to the answer suggesting that addition, but it got moved to chat by a moderator.

So, I suggested an edit directly but my suggested edit was rejected. That's okay. How should I proceed? I want there to be an answer that incorporates all that is already in the existing answer, but just has one more paragraph.

Should I copy and paste the existing content into a new answer and add a paragraph? (Seems redundant)

Should I just add a standalone paragraph as a new answer? (That seems like a bad answer)

Should I make an answer that says it is just adding on to an existing answer? (This seems weird, I don't want to present an incomplete answer)

Comment: Checking the edit history - I can't see that you ever edited the answer. Maybe you should try agian?

Comment: @DaleM I thought I submitted but it was rejected. I don't want to force it if someone has rejected it. Would you have seen that in the history?

Comment: If you click on the "edited" link you see all the edits - there's only one and that was by the OP

Comment: Right, but does a rejected edit show up in that history? I don't have the permission to just outright edit; it goes into a queue and has to be approved. That's where I thought it got rejected from.

Comment: It's here! Don't know if this link works for others: https://law.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/50099

Comment: OK, sorry - edits by users with sufficient rep bypass the queue; I forgot it doesn't work like that for everyone.

Answer (score 5):

I favour your final option which is not weird IMO, and has been used many a-time.

Just post your own answer starting with words to the effect "in addition to phoog's answer..."

See these as examples:

- https://law.stackexchange.com/a/78009/35069
- https://law.stackexchange.com/a/4023/35069
- https://law.stackexchange.com/a/15643/35069

Answer (score 3):

## Don't edit!

The answerer might have excluded something for a reason to keep it simple. In any way, it has to be presumed to conflict with their intent, if it is a large addition.

## Make your own answer!

If you want to add something in-depth, you put work in that is worth it. You shall be rewarded for that with votes. So make your own answer, possibly referencing the already existing one or glossing over the topic and pointing to the other answer before making your addition. Please do link to that answer if you know how to though.